# Jquery backbone view out side call

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

but i try this is not work, what is directory.views.SearchPage for?
can i call this function as above?
thanks for your sharing!

```
directory.views.SearchPage = Backbone.View.extend({

templateLoader: directory.utils.templateLoader,
EmployeeListView: directory.views.EmployeeListView,

initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template(this.templateLoader.get('search-page'));
},

render: function(eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.listView = new directory.views.EmployeeListView({el: $('ul', this.el), model:this.model});
    this.listView.render();
    //var thiskey = ' ';
    //this.model.findByName();
    //alert("HELLO WORLD!1");
    return this;
},
events: {
    "keyup .search-key": "search"
},
// Start the search function
search: function(event) {
    var key = $('.search-key').val();
    this.model.findByName(key);
}
});
```

i try to learning Jquery, but i get some stuck here... please make some help below:

I have a SearchView of Backbone below, i want page load run this SearchView, i code a events page "ready" and "load", but no trigger when page loaded...

i have a question how to make page load run this function? or how to call this SearchView backbone in out side function?

```
    SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html( template );
    },
    events: {
        "click input[type=button]": "doSearch",
        "keyup": "doSearch",
        "load": "doSearch",
  "ready": "doSearch"  
    },
    doSearch: function( event ){
        // Button clicked, you can access the element that was clicked with event.currentTarget
        alert( "Search for " + $("#search_input").val() );
    }
});

var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do this to instantiate your view after the page has loaded.

```
var search_view ;

// jQuery loads yoru view on document ready
$(function () {
    search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
});
```

If you want to call the doSearch function externally you just neeed to do this:

```
search_view.doSearch();
```

Assuming that you want to execute doSearch upon the page load, you may want to add it to the initialize method after the `this.render();` call

Comment: Your welcome, if it worked for you, do you mind upvoting my answer and  accepting it as the correct answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks dcarson, but i still have a question for another type, can u make a help again please? please see my question above, i add some sample code there.

Comment: Maybe you should should edit your post and ask the second question separately in a new question? They are two different questions.

Comment: ok, i am fresh on this forum, thanks!
i posted a title "Jquery Backbone.View.extend function call"

Comment: Thanks, Now could you upvote and accept the answer to this question if you think it is correct? Then I'll help you with the next one :)

Comment: pls wait, system said my reputation not enough !_!
i will upvote this later! many thanks!

Comment: please help my another question...if you can, i stuck this question 3 days ago...